# Object creation and delete in C++

Tags: c++, object, operator-overloading, pass-by-value, copy-elision

I have below very simple code to understand C++ object creation and delete. The output is not really what I expected. Why?

```
class Box{

    public:
        static int count;
        Box(double x, double y, double z) : length(x),width(y),height(z){
            cout << "Box object created with " << length << " " << width << " " << height << endl;
            count++;
            cout << "Count after creation: " << count << endl;
        }
    
        ~Box(){
            cout << "Object deleted!" << endl;
            count--;
            cout << "Count after delete: " << count << endl;
        }        
    
        Box operator + (Box *b){
            return Box(length + b -> length, width + b -> width, height + b -> height);
        }
    
        Box operator + (Box b){
            return Box(length + b.length, width + b.width, height + b.height);
        }
    
    private:
        double length;
        double width;
        double height;
};

int Box::count = 0;

int main()
{    
    Box b1 = Box(1,1,1);
    Box b2 = Box(2,2,2);
    Box b3 = b1 + b2;
    cout << "Here I am expecting 3, but get 2: " << Box::count << endl;

    return 0;    
}
```

I run the code and got below output:

```
Box object created with 1 1 1
Count after creation: 1
Box object created with 2 2 2
Count after creation: 2
Box object created with 3 3 3
Count after creation: 3
Object deleted!
Count after delete: 2
Here I am expecting 3, but get 2: 2.   // I am expecting 3 there, b1, b2 and b3
Object deleted!
Count after delete: 1
Object deleted!
Count after delete: 0
Object deleted!
Count after delete: -1 // how can this been negative!
```

Comment: You are violating _the_ most important rule in C++ class design, the [_rule-of-three_ or _rule-of-five_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three): If you define your own destructor, you almost always should define your own copy/move constructors and assignment operators as well.

Comment: Because you didn't cover all constructors. There are also the copy constructor and the move constructor that get generated automatically. (You can postpone learning about the move constructor, and start reading about the copy one. Adding one would disable the move constructor anyway.)

Comment: The statement `Box b3 = b1 + b2;` is *copy-initializing* the `b3` object. But you don't have a copy-constructor to increase the counter.

Comment: The compiler synthesized `Box(Box const&)` does not do your customized `++count;`.

Comment: If you are going to try and track the objects being created and deleted, you should be printing `this` in your messages instead of just "Object deleted!" and "Box object created with...".  If you had done that, you would see that some of the objects being deleted are not the same as the one's you created that shows the "creation" message.  Then the question you would have asked yourself is "where do these objects that are being deleted coming from?".  The answer is given by the comments made by others already.

Comment: Important terminology: the objects are getting **destroyed**; that's what the destructor does. Nothing is being **deleted**; you delete objects that you create with `new`: `Box *box = new Box(1, 1, 1); delete box;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's not actually copy-initializing `b3`, due to NVRO.  It's copy-initializing `b` in `operator + (Box b)`. Note the deletion before `Here I am expecting 3, but get 2`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat As I know the default move constructor is not defined by the compiler if there is explicitly defined the destructor.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Touché.

Answer (score 4):

The unexpected behavior of the program is related to the declaration of the `operator +`:

```
Box operator + (Box b){
    return Box(length + b.length, width + b.width, height + b.height);
}
```

As the parameter does not accept an argument by reference then in this declaration

```
Box b3 = b1 + b2;
```

that is equivalent to

```
Box b3 = b1.operator +( b2 );
```

there is created a new object for the parameter `Box b` of the operator function using the default copy constructor. This object has the same value of `count` that is equal to `2` as the object `b2`.

Then due to the copy/move elision in this declaration

```
Box b3 = b1 + b2;
```

there is created the object `b3` using the constructor

```
    Box(double x, double y, double z) : length(x),width(y),height(z){
        cout << "Box object created with " << length << " " << width << " " << height << endl;
        count++;
        cout << "Count after creation: " << count << endl;
    }
```

So the value of `count` for this object is equal to `3`.

On the other hand, the parameter created in the `operator +` is deleted using the destructor. As a result the value of `count` is decremented and now is equal to `2` though there are alive `3` objects.

And these messages

```
Count after creation: 3
Object deleted!        // <===
Count after delete: 2  // <===
```

report about the deletion of the local object (parameter) of the operator functon.

So when the last object is destroyed the value of `count` becomes equal to `-1`.

You could declare the `operator +` the following way

```
Box operator + (const Box &b){
    return Box(length + b.length, width + b.width, height + b.height);
}
```

to get the expected result. In this case a redundant object of the type `Box` using the default copy constructor will not be created because the object `b2` will be passed to the `operator +` by reference and neither intermediate object of the type `Box` will be created.

Otherwise you need to define the copy constructor explicitly incrementing `count` for a created new object.